# How to get the parent selector of child element css

Tags: css

I have those html tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .sidebar-group-button .sidebar-group-label:has(~ a.inertia-link-active) {
      color: #677487 !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sidebar-section">
    <button aria-expanded="true" class="sidebar-section-title">
      <span class="sidebar-label">
        <span class="sidebar-icon">
          <!-- Your SVG icon code here -->
        </span>
        **<span class="sidebar-section-label">Resources</span>** // add text-color #677487
      </span>
    </button>
    <div class="mt-1 space-y-1">
      <div class="sidebar-group">
        <button class="sidebar-group-button mt-3">
          <h4 class="sidebar-group-title">
            <span class="sidebar-group-icon"></span>
           ** <span class="sidebar-group-label">Access Controls</span>** // add text-color #677487
          </h4>
        </button>
        <div class="sidebar-item">
          <a class="sidebar-item-title relative **inertia-link-active**" href="/admin/resources /permissions">
            <span class="sidebar-item-icon"></span> // if inertia-link-active exist
            <span class="sidebar-item-label flex items-center">Permissions <!----></span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-item">
          <a class="sidebar-item-title relative" href="/admin/resources/roles">
            <span class="sidebar-item-icon"></span>
            <span class="sidebar-item-label flex items-center">Roles <!----></span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-item">
          <a class="sidebar-item-title relative" href="/admin/resources/users">
            <span class="sidebar-item-icon"></span>
            <span class="sidebar-item-label flex items-center">Users <!----></span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!---->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What I am trying now is I want to add the text-color #677487 to the class sidebar-section-label and sidebar-group-label if  inertia-link-active class exist in the href tag.I don't know how to get the selector of sidebar-section-label and sidebar-group-label from the inertia-link-active class.This is the ui reference.I want to change text color of #677487 to Resources and Access Controls.
UI images links:
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wukLT.png)
What I am getting
[What I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzqim.png)

```
 <style>
    .sidebar-group-button .sidebar-group-label:has(~ a.inertia-link-active) {
      color: #677487 !important;
    }
  </style>
```

I am trying this css.But it does not work and the text color does not change.
`your text`

Comment: @Roy I tried with has like i shown in my code but it does not work.My selector relationship is more complicated

Comment: You have three HTML errors. Check the validator and fix those first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.sidebar-group-button .sidebar-group-label:has(~ a.inertia-link-active)
```

You are trying to apply `:has()` in the wrong position here. It is not your `.sidebar-group-label` element, that has any such *siblings* here.

What you want to check, is if `.sidebar-group-button` has a *sibling*, that *contains* a link with that class - and then select the `.sidebar-group-label` inside that button.

So that would be something like

```
.sidebar-group-button:has(+ .sidebar-item a.inertia-link-active) .sidebar-group-label
```

Comment: Many thanks.It works.